# Encoded Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript encoded into my html is not working. It is supposed to find the best out of the players listed, and then alert who is the best. When I run it, all of the HTML and CSS aspects show, but there is no alert. Please help. It might just be a syntax error or something but please still help! Here is the code:

```
<script>
            var players = [
                {name: "Pat Moran", overall: 67, position: 1},
                {name: "Peter Webb", overall: 81, position: 1},
                {name: "Ramiro Ramirez", overall: 74, position: 1}
            ];

            function findBestPlayer() {
                var bestSoFar = 0;
                var bestPlayer;
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    if (players[i].overall > bestSoFar) {
                        bestPlayer = players[i];
                        bestSoFar = players[i].overall;
                    }
                }
                return best;
            }

            var bestPlayer = findBestPlayer();
            alert("Best player is " + bestPlayer.name + " with an overall of " + bestPlayer.overall ;
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`return best;` is not defined - use `return bestPlayer;` in that place, and include a brace after the alert end

Answer (score 1):

```js
            var players = [
                {name: "Pat Moran", overall: 67, position: 1},
                {name: "Peter Webb", overall: 81, position: 1},
                {name: "Ramiro Ramirez", overall: 74, position: 1}
            ];

            function findBestPlayer() {
                var bestSoFar = 0;
                var bestPlayer;
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    if (players[i].overall > bestSoFar) {
                        bestPlayer = players[i];
                        bestSoFar = players[i].overall;
                    }
                }

                return bestPlayer;
            }

            var bestPlayer = findBestPlayer();
            alert("Best player is " + bestPlayer.name + " with an overall of " + bestPlayer.overall) ;
```

The closing parenthesis is missing for the alert function.
Edit : corrected the bestPlayer instead of best. Thanks to runner and joseph.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this mobily, so I can't debug it, but in the function findBestPlayer you return best instead of bestPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

here best is not defined and missing brackets in alert

```
 var players = [
                {name: "Pat Moran", overall: 67, position: 1},
                {name: "Peter Webb", overall: 81, position: 1},
                {name: "Ramiro Ramirez", overall: 74, position: 1}
            ];

            function findBestPlayer() {
                var bestSoFar = 0;
                var bestPlayer;
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    if (players[i].overall > bestSoFar) {
                        bestPlayer = players[i];
                        bestSoFar = players[i].overall;
                    }
                }
                return bestPlayer;
            }
          var bestPlayer = findBestPlayer();
            alert("Best player is " + bestPlayer.name + " with an overall of " + bestPlayer.overall) ;
```